# CSS shape as a link

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get a div with a CSS shape to function as a link.

I can get the div with the shape to show up, the link tag also is rendered, but I can't actually get the link tag to fill up the div so to say.

Is there anything I'm missing?

JSFiddle:  [CSS Shape Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuzimaster/H2J9a/)

HTML code:

```
<div style="width: 0px; 
height: 0px; 
border-left: 7px solid transparent; 
border-right: 7px solid transparent; 
border-top: 12px solid #d1e8ff;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;">
   <a href=\"{0}\" style=\"display:block; height:13px; width:12px; align:\"></a>  
</div>
```

Did the styles inline so that you don't have to read the classses separately.

Comment: Why not apply all styling to the a itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the other way round, the anchor needs to wrap the div: http://jsfiddle.net/H2J9a/2/

Also, you don't need to escape the quotes.

In your case, the borders are pushing the anchor below the div, so you can either try making the anchor absolutely positioned so it floats above the div, or put the shape styles on the anchor itself. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/H2J9a/6/.

This is an example of the anchor having the shape styles (the div is unnecessary here, although I kept it):

```
<div style="">
    <a href="{0}" style="width: 0px; 
                         height: 0px; 
                         border-left: 7px solid transparent; 
                         border-right: 7px solid transparent;
                         border-top: 12px solid #d1e8ff;
                         display: inline-block;
                         vertical-align: middle;">
    </a>  
</div>
```

Comment: I was using .NET code behind to bind the tag, hence the escapes.  There are other divs before and after, so I'll probably take this one since it melds with the syntactic flow of the page better.

Comment: I thought so, just make sure you don't have them in the output HTML. Yeah, you have plenty options to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the anchor without the div

http://jsfiddle.net/H2J9a/5/

```
<a href="#" style="width: 0px; 
    height: 0px; 
    border-left: 7px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 7px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 12px solid #d1e8ff;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a div at all

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H2J9a/7/)

**CSS**

```
a {
    display:block; 
    height:0px; 
    width:0px;
    border: 7px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 7px solid #d1e8ff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try wrapping the div with `<a></a>` instead of other way around.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/H2J9a/1/)**

```
<a href="www.google.com" style="display:block; height:13px; width:12px; align:"><div style="width: 0px; 
    height: 0px; 
    border-left: 7px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 7px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 12px solid #d1e8ff;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;">
</div>

   </a>
```

Comment: Note that this creates 'invalid' HTML according to the W3C standard. There can't be block elements within an anchor.

Comment: I think html5 allows this behavior

Comment: It seems I'm holding on to old standards, this indeed is allowed in HTML5. http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: I didn't knew about previous standards. A man should be aware of his history